# Cluster certain markers always together

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I am having a GeoJSON dataset of venues in different cities.
Is it possible to cluster only items belonging to one city together?

A naive way I could think of would be to create a layer for each city myself and place the cities items in them?
That would amount to like over 60 geojson layers.

Comment: Yup, creating several clusters is the way to go in these scenarios. "60 geojson layers" does not mean that there will be noticeable overhead.

Comment: To support @IvanSanchez statement, I already used much more than 60 MarkerClusterGroups on a map without any trouble.